# Java tetrahedron surface area and volume code

Tags: java

When I run this code, I'm getting the wrong output for computeArea() and computeVolume().
Logically, I believe the formulas are correct. 
For example, the input for a tetrahedron is side length of 4 (equilateral triangle), height of 5. The correct answer is 37.72 for area and 11.55 for volume. What my code is putting out is 27.71 for area and 0.0 for volume.
So I'm pretty confused on why it wouldn't be working.
There's a lot more code involving this so I'm putting the segment that I think the problem is at. 
Thanks in advance!!

```
    public double computeArea()
    {

        double tetrahedronSurfaceArea;
        tetrahedronSurfaceArea = 4*((Math.sqrt(3)/4) *side*side);
        return tetrahedronSurfaceArea;
    }

    public double computeVolume()
    {
        double tetrahedronVolume;
        tetrahedronVolume = (1/3) * (((Math.sqrt(3))/4)*side*side) * height;
        return tetrahedronVolume;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String tetrahedronResult = "area is " + computeArea() + "\n";
        tetrahedronResult = tetrahedronResult + "volume is " + computeVolume() + "\n";
        return tetrahedronResult;
    }
```

Comment: You do realise that if all the edges of a tetrahedron have length 4, the height can't POSSIBLY be 5, right?  It would be 4 * sqrt (2/3).  Your maths is in error.

Comment: My teacher assigned that the side length be 4 and the height is 5 :/

Comment: But that is not physically possible; so there is no correct answer for either the surface area or the volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that at least one of the operands is a floating point number when doing integer division otherwise the result will be truncated.

In Java `int/int` yields an `int` causing the fractional digits to be truncated.

When the `numerator` < `denominator` the result will always be truncated to `0`

```
tetrahedronVolume = (1/3.0) * (((Math.sqrt(3))/4)*side*side) * height;
```

Comment: Integer Division strike again!

Comment: Ah man. Well computeVolume is now putting out the correct answer but computeArea is putting out the same incorrect answer even after I tried putting at least one of the operands as a floating point, tried it with every number individually, then all of them at once, etc