# Why does my function keep failing my JUnit test?

Tags: java, function, testing, methods, junit

This is one of my classes that I am testing. It keeps failing the calculateVolume() method and I am not sure why.

```
   package shape3D;


public class Sphere implements Cloneable {
    private double myRadius;
    private double myVolume;
    private double mySurfaceArea;
    private final static double pi = 3.14;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Sphere sphere = new Sphere();
    }
    public double calculateVolume(){
        myVolume = (4/3)*pi*(Math.pow(myRadius,3));
        return myVolume;
    }
     public double calculateSurfaceArea(){
         mySurfaceArea = ((4)*(pi)*(Math.pow(myRadius,2)));
         return mySurfaceArea;
     }
     public double getSurfaceArea(){
         return this.calculateSurfaceArea();
     }
     public double getVolume(){
         return this.calculateVolume();
     }
     public void setRadius(double radius2){
         myRadius = radius2;
     }

     public String toString(){
            return "Volume: " + this.getVolume() + "   Surface area " + this.getSurfaceArea();
        }
     public Sphere clone (){
            Sphere p = new Sphere();
            p.setRadius(myRadius);
            return p;
        }

}
```

Here is the JUnit test case I am using

```
public class sphereTest {
    @Test
    public void testSphere(){
        shape3D.Sphere sphere = new shape3D.Sphere();
        sphere.setRadius(6);
        assertTrue(sphere.calculateSurfaceArea()== 452.16);
        assertTrue(sphere.calculateVolume()== 904.32);
```

The calculateSurfaceArea() stuff passes fine but the volume is failing and I am not sure why.

Comment: Did you try to print what `sphere.calculateVolume()` returns...?

Comment: `(4/3)*pi*(Math.pow(6,3))` is not 904.32...

Comment: it gives me 678.24 for the first test case where the radius is 6. No clue how that happened

Comment: @Falmarri He set "pi" to be 3.14.

Comment: See the related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708028/java-tetrahedron-surface-area-and-volume-code

Answer (score 3):

You're doing integer division when calculating the volume truncating the first term of the equation to `1`. Replace

```
myVolume = (4 / 3) * pi * (Math.pow(myRadius, 3)); // 678.24
```

with

```
myVolume = (4 / 3.0) * pi * (Math.pow(myRadius, 3)); // 904.31
```

Due to floating point imprecision you will still need to allow for the difference between the expected & calculated values. You can use this version of [`assertEquals`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28double,%20double,%20double%29) which allows a delta value to do the comparison - replace

```
assertTrue(sphere.calculateVolume()== 904.32);
```

with

```
assertEquals(sphere.calculateVolume(), 904.32, .02);
```

Answer (score 3):

The calculation

```
myVolume = (4/3)*pi*(Math.pow(myRadius,3));
```

Uses integer arithmetic: `4/3` evaluates to `1`.

Change it to

```
myVolume = (4.0/3)*pi*(Math.pow(myRadius,3));
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite aside from the 4/3 integer problem (which I failed to spot): It's not safe to compare two Java double values this way.

If you use `assertEquals` instead of `assertTrue` then you might see the problem. I'm betting that it's calculating 4/3 first, then truncating it. And it'll still do this even if you make those into doubles.

Use the overload for assertEquals as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242224/junit-difference-between-assertequalsdouble-double-and-assertequalsdouble-d).

Comment: And there's an overload for assertEquals that take a delta for approximate comparison.

Comment: Hah, I was just looking for an example of that :)